# Which objects own the method? Translating from discrete math

Tags: oop, discrete-mathematics

So, suppose I'm working in the world of discrete mathematics and I have some function

`f: A x B x C -> D`.

With this function I can make computations like `f(a,b,c) = d`.  (I'm being vague here on purpose).

Now suppose I want to implement this computation explicitly in some modern OO programming language.  So I initialize a variable called `a` of class `ClassA` and so on with `b` and `c`.  Then what?  Which object should **own** the computation?  Or could it be an initializer.  Could it be a static function?

I could have:

- `d = a.f_1(b,c)`,
- `d = b.f_2(a,c)`,
- `d = c.f_3(a,b)`,
- `d = new ObjD(a,b,c)`,
- `d = ZStatic.f_4(a,b,c)`

all as plausible options, couldn't I?

Given the situation, should symmetry demand I implement all of these options?

I'd prefer to avoid the constructor approach completely, but beyond that I don't know what progress could be made other than the assumption of essentially arbitrary information.

So, what object should own the function $f$, if any?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To give the best answer, it is important to know what kind of variables you use.

A very important metric in oop is to achieve **high cohesion**. Cohesion is the degree to which the elements of a module belong together. If your variables a,b and c belong together in a specific context, then it should be the best solution to put them in exactly one class. And if they are in one class you should not worry about, which class should own the computation (your fourth solution).

Your last suggestion, to use a static function is also conceivable. This approach is often used in mathematic librarys in different kind of languages (e.g. Java: [Math class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html))